# Automatic Image-scrolling control

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, image

I need help with a "**Automatic Image-scroller**". The scenario is quite simple. I've got one single picture, and it should move up and when it moves out of frame, the same picture would appear beneath itself and continue to move up. Kind of a loop.

[image: Image-scroller]

The problem is that i haven't got a single clue how to make it in **code-behind** nor **XAML**, but it has to written in "code-behind" cause of the things i'm hooking it up with.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: If you can do it in XAML translating that to c# or vb.net usually is rather trivial.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry because I totally misled you there. I can't do it in XAML either...

Comment: Then your statement is rather misleading, as it sounds like you actually can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using an `ImageBrush`, given that you do not need to see the outside of said frame:

```xml
<Border Height="300" Width="300">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <RectAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(ImageBrush.Viewport)"
                                    To="0,0,1,1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <Border.Background>
        <ImageBrush
                ImageSource="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3736a467816b5100e6bac91847cae8b6?s=128&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG"
                Viewport="0,1,1,1" TileMode="Tile" />
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

As a C# method (the hierachical style is not necessary of course, this is just closer to the XAML, i hope you can read C#, if not [this converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) might be quite handy):

```cs
private Border CreateScrollingImage(string path)
{
    var anim = new RectAnimation() { To = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("Background.(ImageBrush.Viewport)"));
    var imageConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();

    return new Border()
    {
        Width = 300, Height = 300,
        Style = new Style()
        {
            TargetType = typeof(Border),
            Triggers =
            {
                new System.Windows.EventTrigger()
                {
                    RoutedEvent = FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent,
                    Actions =
                    {
                        new BeginStoryboard()
                        {
                            Storyboard = new Storyboard()
                            {
                                Children =
                                {
                                    anim
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Background = new ImageBrush()
        {
            ImageSource = (ImageSource)imageConverter.ConvertFromString(path),
            Viewport = new Rect(0, 1, 1, 1),
            TileMode = TileMode.Tile
        }
    };
}
```

```
controls.Add(CreateScrollingImage("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3736a467816b5100e6bac91847cae8b6?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"));
```

You may want to change the `Stretch` on the `ImageBrush` if you need the image to be uniform.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time doing this, really appreciated it.

Comment: You're welcome, it was quite interesting for me too, glad it helped :)

Comment: Just discovered an error: `Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Windows.Media.Animation.RectAnimation' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.TimelineCollection'. E:\VB.NET\WPF\slot machine\slot_machine\MainWindow.xaml.vb 127 74 slot_machine`

What is wrong? Can't get it to work :(

Comment: This has nothing to do with my code, which works. You probably try to assign the animation to `Storyboard.Children` when you should use `Storyboard.Children.Add` instead. (My code may look like it is an assignment too but i use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), [they also exist in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) but may work differently)

Comment: The error highlights { 
                                    anim 
                                } 
, in your code. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Is that code in a C# class or not? As noted the code works for me, and as also noted you do not need to do it that way, `Children = { anim }` is exactly the same as `Children.Add(anim)`.

Comment: It's not in c# class, it's vb.net, I used the converter, but I can't get it to work anyway. I would really appreciate if you'd convert it into vb and see if it works for you.

Comment: I do not speak VB, you cannot expect that you can copy C# code and it will still work. Use `Children.Add`. VB.NET initializer should be something like `Children = New TimelineCollection From { anim }`, seriously, read the manual yourself please.

Comment: @H.B., Thanks for the sample !  Do you think it would be possible to do this but instead of automatizing the background movement, it would be done with the mouse ?  (i.e. if you drag/drop with the mouse the image to the bottom, it will "circle" like you did it with the animation).

Comment: @Shimrod: That surely would be possible, but quite a bit more complex. You probably would need to find and handle the respective mouse drag events, get the respective delta from the event arguments and apply it to the image brush viewport. [`ManipulationDelta`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta.aspx) might be a suitable event for this, though designed for touch those usually work for mouse drags as well.